# On how to do postbacks manually, passing objects and raising events in ASP.NET user controls

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, event-handling, postback

I'm trying to create a custom calendar as an ASP.NET 4 user control to do many complicate things (I haven't found anything suiting my needs on the 'net).

I managed to create the calendar, pass existing events, handle multiple event types, and stuff.

What I'm not able to do is, when the user clicks on a day, pass to the page containing the user control a `DateTime` with the day clicked.

My problem is that there are no web controls in my user control (like `LinkButton`s), the calendar is a `<table />`, and each day is a `<td />`, so I have to manually raise postbacks when the user clicks on a `<td />`.

I tried reading stuff around the 'net, but every tutorial and blog post is about doing postbacks through web controls, and not doing it manually.

The primary things I need to understand are:

1. How do I pass the `DateTime` along with the postback (if it's the correct thing to do)? The `ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference` method expects a `String` as its second parameter, not an object.
2. How can I realize a behavior like the one exposed by `DropDownList`'s `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event? I mean, something like my user control declares an event `DayClicked` raised when the user clicks on a day's `<td />` which I consume in the page implementing the control.

While answering please be aware I'm not so skilled in using events and delegates (those things are some kind of diabolical trickery to me).

### **Here be codez**

This is a brief example (without all the stuff I need but not relevant to obtain the goal) of what I have right now.

**Example.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Example.ascx.cs" Inherits="ExampleControl" %>

<asp:PlaceHolder ID="Content" runat="server" />
```

**Example.ascx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class ExampleControl : UserControl
{
    public Int32 Year { get; set; }

    public Int32 Month { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // If the year has not been set.
        if (this.Year == 0)
        {
            // Set the year to the current year.
            this.Year = DateTime.Today.Year;
        }

        // If the month has not been set.
        if (this.Month == 0)
        {
            // Set the month to the current month.
            this.Month = DateTime.Today.Month;
        }

        // Create the calendar table.
        Table calendar = new Table();

        // Display grid.
        calendar.GridLines = GridLines.Both;

        // Create the calendar header (a row with the name of the days).
        TableRow calendarHeader = new TableRow();

        // Place the header in thead instead of tbody.
        calendarHeader.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

        // Add the days of the week.
        for (Int32 dayOfWeek = 0; dayOfWeek < 7; dayOfWeek++)
        {
            // Create the cell for the day.
            TableCell dayHeader = new TableCell();

            // Set the name of the day using the current UI culture.
            dayHeader.Text = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedDayName((DayOfWeek) dayOfWeek);

            // Add the day to the header.
            calendarHeader.Cells.Add(dayHeader);
        }

        // Add the header to the calendar.
        calendar.Rows.Add(calendarHeader);

        // Create the row for the first week.
        TableRow weekRow = new TableRow();

        // Add the days of the month.
        for (DateTime day = new DateTime(this.Year, this.Month, 1); day.Year == this.Year && day.Month == this.Month; day = day.AddDays(1))
        {
            // If it's the first day of the month.
            if (day.Day == 1)
            {
                // Place enough spacers to have the first day under the right day of the week.
                for (Int32 spacer = 0; spacer < (Int32) day.DayOfWeek; spacer++)
                {
                    // Add the spacer to the week.
                    weekRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                }
            }

            // If it's a new week.
            if (day.Day != 1 && day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
                // Add the previous week to the calendar.
                calendar.Rows.Add(weekRow);

                // Create a new row for the new week.
                weekRow = new TableRow();
            }

            // Create the cell for the day.
            TableCell dayCell = new TableCell();

            // When the user clicks the cell do a postback.
            dayCell.Attributes.Add("onclick", this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "DayClicked"));

            // Display the day of the month.
            dayCell.Text = Convert.ToString(day.Day);

            // Add the day to the week.
            weekRow.Cells.Add(dayCell);

            // If it's the last day of the month.
            if (day.Day == DateTime.DaysInMonth(this.Year, this.Month))
            {
                // Place enough spacers to fill up the week.
                for (Int32 spacer = (Int32) day.DayOfWeek; spacer < 6; spacer++)
                {
                    // Add the spacer to the week.
                    weekRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                }
            }
        }

        // Add the last week to the calendar.
        calendar.Rows.Add(weekRow);

        // Add the calendar to the control.
        this.Content.Controls.Add(calendar);
    }
}
```

**Example.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Example.aspx.cs" Inherits="ExamplePage" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Example.ascx" TagPrefix="ex" TagName="Calendar" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
            <h1>Example</h1>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <ex:Calendar ID="Calendar" Year="2011" Month="3" runat="server" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Example.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class ExamplePage : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have the client script update a hidden field with the day that was clicked before calling the code to post back. Then, you'll be able to get the value from the hidden field on the server.

With this approach, you wouldn't be passing the day clicked in the postback arguments. So, you can call GetPostBackEventReference without custom arguments.

Personally, I would opt to create this as a custom server control instead of a user control. You could implement [IPostBackDataHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkhywh0b.aspx). In the LoadPostData method, if the value of the hidden field changed, you would return True, which would trigger .net to call the RaisePostDataChangedEvent method that you would code with the method that would raise your changed event.